# Using the sort in Query to sort booleans

Tags: orchardcms

There may be a better way to do this but my client has a list of books they want displayed. A number of them are by the society itself and they want them to display first before any of the other books.  I set up a custom type called "books for sale" and I added a boolean field indicating that this was a society book.

I created a query "all books" in which I sorted against the title and then the boolean field however it does not sort preferring to display numbers first followed by an alphabetical listing.

Is there a way to do this so those books that have been flagged as "true" display first in the list?

Kind Regards

Simon

Answer (score 0):

You should sort by boolean field first and the title second, not the other way around.

Sorting by multiple columns is done like prioritizing - it means that collection will be sorted by the first column, and if there are any rows with the same value of that column, only then will those rows be sorted by the second column. If there are some rows with the same values in those 2 columns, the sort would be performed by the third sorting column if there is one. And so on..

Comment: If it worked, you could mark the answer as the accepted one. To do so, click on the check mark right below the votes for an answer from the left side of an answer..